# Event Tracing for Windows

Tags: windows, event-tracking, event-viewer

I am using Sysmon to collect logs on windows and I have got to know from TrustedSec Github page that Sysmon uses Event Tracing for Windows(ETW) to collect it's logs. Now I am trying to figure out the if Sysmon can capture more logs compared to Windows Event Viewer. For that I'm confused from where Windows Event Viewer collects logs. Is it Event Tracing for Windows(ETW) itself?

Comment: ETW is a generic mechanism for tracing/logging. Sysmon implements a provider (in the driver) for writing events and a consumer (in the process) for reading events. Event Viewer  can only show events for providers that register their schemas with the system. Windows implements many providers that do this, while Sysmon is using ETW just as a message transport.

Comment: @Luke Do u have any resource I can refer to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/about-event-tracing

Comment: @Luke So can Sysmon capture more logs compared to Event viewer?

Comment: Turns out I was wrong about sysmon. I assumed it was similar to procmon but it's not. It is purely an event provider and installs its event manifest so event viewer can display its events. Regardless, that's a bit of a nonsensical question. Event viewer just displays event data; it's the providers that generate the data. Sysmon generates its own custom events; event viewer can display them as well as events from any other installed provider.

Comment: @Luke Apologies. I meant how Sysmon compares to Native Windows event logs.

Comment: Sysmon generates a (couple dozen events)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon#events]. Various Windows components generate thousands if not more. The Sysmon events are more concerned with high-level security status while the various Windows components are more concerend with low-level functional status. I don't know if there's a comprehensive listing of all the components and events they log.